# Logstash 404 errors when dealing with UPDATES after INSERTS

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a logstash config like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/home/csdata/*.data"]
    codec => json {
      }
    start_position => "beginning"
    discover_interval => 5
 }
}
output{
if [_up] == 1 {
 elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        host => "[myelasticsearchip]"
        cluster => "clustername"
        flush_size => 50
        index => "%{_index}"
        action => "update"
        document_id => "%{_id}"
        index_type => "%{_type}"
        }
}
else if [_id] != "" {
  elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        host => "[myelasticsearchip]"
        cluster => "clustername"
        flush_size => 50
        index => "%{_index}"
        document_id => "%{_id}"
        index_type => "%{_type}"
        }
 }
else{
  elasticsearch {
       protocol => "http"
        host => "[myelasticsearchip]"
        cluster => "clustername"
        index => "%{_index}"
         flush_size => 50
        index_type => "%{_type}"
        }
    }
}
```

I have a ton of

```
failed action with response of 404, dropping action:
```

The data should all be coming into the same file and in order, so things should be created before they are being updated. This doesn't happen with ALL items, but with plenty. I would expect to have none of these errors.

Is this because of the different flush_sizes? Eventhough the items are in order in the original file, meaning an INSERT always comes before an UPDATE.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anything in your elasticsearch logs?

Comment: I couldn't figure this out and eventually just move this part of the app outside of logstash.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help

i had same problem, and found elasticsearch log

`404 index_not_found_exception`

and my solution is enable elastic auto create index

since my index looks like logstash_api-20160112

in elasticsearch.yml add

action.auto_create_index: +logstash_api-*